# UIWebView wrapper vs. native components

Tags: ios, architecture, uiwebview

I have been doing some research before beginning my first iOS app, and I was wondering - what are some advantages and disadvantages of creating a mobile web app and wrapping it in a UIWebView vs. native components and classes?

I've read about [OkCupid discussing their issues with the web view and caching](http://www.quora.com/OKCupid/What-framework-does-OKCupid-use-for-their-iOS-application).

Can anyone share their thoughts on what might be the most appropriate route?

Comment: How is wrapping a web app into an "app" better than just letting users use it the way they were supposed to, inside a browser? There is no argument that should convince you to go wrapper over native apps, ever.

Comment: @ficheck - That is essentially what I'm asking, as I've seen and used numerous apps architected in each way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user, I prefer to use an app made natively for the device, rather than web app.  I consider it somewhat lame when I download an app from the app store only to discover that it's simply a UIWebView.  The only reason (as a developer) that you might consider doing this is because you do not have the resources needed to make a native app, yet you would still like to distribute your web app in the same way as you would a normal, native application.

In other words, if you can, don't make a web app.  Using the native iOS frameworks gives you a more rich set of libraries and tools, and generally produces an app that feels more natural and works a lot more seamlessly.

Comment: I think many users do not notice, and in some cases web views scroll faster than a UITableView ever could with many subviews, etc.

Comment: +1.  Also, wrapping a web-based app means you're dependent on connectivity (can't use on a plane, etc).